How to force installation of snaps immediately?
I am using snap to deploy software on a workstation where multiple users are working on. Whenever there is an update of a snap package, the balloon tip appears mentioning: "Close the application to update now. It will update automatically in 13 days.
As there are multiple users simultaneously using the software, it requires all of them to terminate the application in order for update to occur. So my question is:

Is there any way to force the update without the waiting time and with the applications still running?
As it states in the message that after 13 days it will automatically update. For me, this implies that it is possible to update the application even if it is still running.

Is there a way to reduce the number of days?



"For me, this implies that it is possible to update the application even if it is still running." No, what will actually happen is that the application will terminate (losing all unsaved work), then the snap will refresh.

@user535733 Thank you for the information. This is good to know. Do you know how I can reduce the time from 14 days to something smaller?
